# Why are lists different to each other if their type and content is the same?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, logical-operators

Here is my riddle:
I have 4 lists, each one is a list, and each one has numbers 1, 2 and 3, in that precise order.
The following code shows that all four lists are type `list`, but for some reason, all four lists are different from each other.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = list(a)
c = list([1, 2, 3])
d = list((1, 2, 3))
types = ([type(x) for x in [a, b, c, d]])
```

The type of all four is:

```
>>> types
[list, list, list, list]
```

But when I ask if they are the same as the others, I get a shocking `False` as an answer:
I just created a `DataFrame` in order to show the results in a clear way:

```
import pandas as pd
relations = pd.DataFrame([[x is y for x in [a, b, c, d]] for y in [a, b, c, d]],
                  index=["a", "b", "c", "d"], columns=["a", "b", "c", "d"])
```

Here is the result:

```
relations
    a       b       c       d
a   True    False   False   False
b   False   True    False   False
c   False   False   True    False
d   False   False   False   True
```

How can this be happening?

Comment: Your mistake is in using `is` instead of `==`.

Comment: To expand on @jwodder, `is` tests for identity - are the two instances the *same* instance. `==` tests for equality.

Comment: `is` does not compare equality, it compares identity. `a` and `b` might be equal, but they are not the same object.

Comment: `(a == b)` => `True`; `(a is b)` => `False`. In some other languages, "is" checks for class membership, e.g. `if shape is Circle { ... }`.